# How to use Laravel whereBelongsTo with OR condition?

Tags: laravel, relationship

I am building a query step by step:-

```
$query  = $modelClass::with(array(
                            'employeeRegionalCenter',
                            'employeeMembershipCenter',
                            'employeeMembershipCenter.membershipCenterLanguage' => function($languageQuery) {
                                $languageQuery->where('language', App::getLocale());
                            },
                            'employeeLanguage' => function($languageQuery) {
                                $languageQuery->where('language', App::getLocale());
                            }))
                        ->where(array(
                            'deleted_at'    => NULL
                        ));

if(auth()->guard('admin')->user()['type'] === Globals::ADMIN_USER) {
    $query->where(function($orQuery) {
                    $orQuery->where('created_by', new ObjectId(auth()->guard('admin')->user()['_id']))
                            ->orWhere('regional_center_id', new ObjectId(auth()->guard('admin')->user()['_id']));
            });
}
```

Then based on the search key I submitted, I am again putting conditional filtering in the query:-

```
if(isset($request->searchKey) && !empty($request->searchKey) && $request->searchKey !== '')
{
    $searchKey = $request->searchKey;
    $query->where(function ($orQuery) use ($searchKey){
        $orQuery->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
            ->orWhere('mobile', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
            ->orWhere('card_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
            ->orWhereHas('employeeLanguage', function ($languageRelationQuery) use ($searchKey){
                $languageRelationQuery->where(function($languageQueryEn) use($searchKey) {
                                            $languageQueryEn->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                                                            ->where('language', 'en');
                                        })
                                        ->orWhere(function($olanguageQueryAr) use($searchKey) {
                                            $olanguageQueryAr->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                                                            ->where('language', 'ar');
                                        });
            });
    });
}
```

This one is working neat. However, I want to combine a whereBelongsTo(). So this is what I did.

```
if(isset($request->searchKey) && !empty($request->searchKey) && $request->searchKey !== '')
{  
    $data['searchKey']  = $request->searchKey;
    $searchKey          = trim($data['searchKey']);
    $membershipCenters  = MembershipCenter::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')->get();

    if(isset($membershipCenters) && !empty($membershipCenters) && count($membershipCenters) > 0) {
        $query->where(function ($orQuery) use ($searchKey){
                    $orQuery->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                        ->orWhere('mobile', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                        ->orWhere('card_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                        ->orWhereHas('employeeLanguage', function ($languageRelationQuery) use ($searchKey){
                            $languageRelationQuery->where(function($languageQueryEn) use($searchKey) {
                                                        $languageQueryEn->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                                                                        ->where('language', 'en');
                                                    })
                                                    ->orWhere(function($olanguageQueryAr) use($searchKey) {
                                                        $olanguageQueryAr->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                                                                        ->where('language', 'ar');
                                                    });
                        });
                })
                ->orWhere(function($belongsToQuery) use($membershipCenters) {
                    $belongsToQuery->whereBelongsTo($membershipCenters, 'employeeMembershipCenter');
                });
    } else {
        $query->where(function ($orQuery) use ($searchKey){
                $orQuery->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                        ->orWhere('mobile', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                        ->orWhere('card_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                        ->orWhereHas('employeeLanguage', function ($languageRelationQuery) use ($searchKey){
                            $languageRelationQuery->where(function($languageQueryEn) use($searchKey) {
                                                        $languageQueryEn->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                                                                        ->where('language', 'en');
                                                    })
                                                    ->orWhere(function($olanguageQueryAr) use($searchKey) {
                                                        $olanguageQueryAr->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchKey . '%')
                                                                        ->where('language', 'ar');
                                                    });
                        });
            });
    }
}
```

But the result isn't working. When I am combining `whereBelongsTo` with `OR` condition using the `orWhere()`, the data set returns blank. But if simply write

```
$query->whereBelongsTo($membershipCenters, 'employeeMembershipCenter');
```

It works as it intends to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please fix up the code formatting so it's readable. Do what you want in your own code, but if you're asking for help there's no reason to have like 64 characters of whitespace before a line.

Comment: Also this is crazy: `if(isset($membershipCenters) && !empty($membershipCenters) && count($membershipCenters) > 0)`. You just set it in the line before, and the 2 other conditions are checking the same thing. `if ($membershipCenters->count())` will suffice.

Comment: @miken32 I put the white spaces for indentation so that people can understand the nested code blocks. Else they say it becomes unreadable.

Comment: As I said, there's no reason for 16 levels of indent before a line. Too much indent is just as bad as no indent.